# My testing requirement is to try spoofing multiple IPs i.e. using X-Forwarded-For and X-Real both

Tags: wget

I am trying 
 wget  --user-agent=$line  --header="X-Forwarded-For:127.0.5.1" --header="X-Real-IP:199.168.148.148" "http://google.com"

but this is not giving me the desired IP in the logs

Comment: How do you know? Do you have access to Google's logs?

Comment: I just gave an arbitrary url... m hitting a specific url... for which every hit gets recorded in logs in a server... m checking the IP collected in those logs

Comment: Oh, that won't work. You can't spoof the actual client IP by setting one of these headers.

Comment: Actually it works if I spoof 1 Ip using only just X-Forwarded-For header. but my requirement is also to include X-Real with a different IP and see which of the IP is given preference

Comment: Which IP is given preference will depend on the setup of the receiving web server. If you can use `x-forwarded-for` to influence the IP in the server log then it's possible the server is badly configured